# WDK + Windows 8 + MSVC 2010

Tags: visual-c++, windows-8, wdk

ALL,

I would like to build a dokan library. According to [dokan instruction](http://dokan.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/sys/howtobuild.txt) I need the WDK which can be downloaded from the Microsoft website.

Problem is - I have MSVC 2010 and it looks like WDK is for MSVC 2013 and I don't know what to do.

Could someone explain to me where can I get WDK for MSVC 2010?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The Windows 8.x SDK generally works with Visual Studio 2010--with the exception of a few places in the `include\winrt` headers where they used C++11 constructs not supported prior to VS 2012, specifically strongly-typed enumerations. The issue is there is no automatic integration for the VS 2010 toolset.

The recommended solution is to use `.props` files. See the [Visual C++ Team Blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2012/11/23/using-the-windows-8-sdk-with-visual-studio-2010-configuring-multiple-projects.aspx) for details, and I have the fully authored .props files for both x86 and x64 hosted on [my blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2013/10/18/visual-studio-2013-and-windows-8-1-sdk-rtm-are-now-available.aspx). These are also used in my open-source projects ([DirectX Tool Kit](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=248929), [DirectXTex](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=248926), [DirectXMesh](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=324981), [UVAtlas](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=512686), [DXUT](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=320437), [Effects 11](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?LinkId=271568)) which support VS 2010 + the Windows 8.1 SDK.

I believe the situation is basically the same with the Windows Driver Kit 8.x as it actually integrates into the existing Windows 8.x SDK. You will just need to add `include\km` and `lib\km folders` to the .props for the kernel mode projects.

That said, with [VS 2013 Community edition](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/vs2013-community-vs.aspx) being freely available full-featured version of Visual Studio under generous license terms, I'm not sure why you are sticking with VS 2010...

Comment: ,My project is set to be build with MSVC 2008 and I;m building everything with 2010. I just don't want to hit any incompatibility between compilers.

Comment: Now where do I go to get the actual WDK? Now this page: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/hh852365.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396, says I need at least 2012 version. Also, it looks like you use the words SDK/WDK in terchangeably and I need the latter. I don't really care about the version, but I figure since I have Win 8.1 and VS 2010 I might get the latest version of WDK

Comment: To build drivers you use the "WDK" or "Windows Driver Kit". Install the "WDK 8.1 Update (for Windows 8.1, 8, and 7 driver". Then use the .props files I mention above with edits to get the km paths added.

Comment: Well where do I download it from? I have just MSVC 2010 and I can't download it since it check for MSVC 2013 presence. Also, I don't want to build drivers. It looks like WDK headers and libraries are a dependency for building the dokan library as explained in the link I gave in my question.

Comment: Multiple reasons: I will use it in a project that is set up to be built as python bindings and it is built with MSVC 2010. My employer is using 2010 for the build. The product will have to run on XP+. Compatibility. I am not a driver developer and will use it for "build and forget". And finally - why do I need to upgrade for the compiler that is too fresh? ;-)

Comment: FWIW, you can use the ``v120_xp`` Platform Toolset to target Windows XP. Also, VS 2015 may be 'too fresh', but VS 2010 is 'too old' :)

Comment: Does v120_xp has same header set as WDK and same library functionality? Can it be safely used instead of WDK? Once again because of the compatibility I don't want to use fresh MSVC version and I don't want to develop any drivers. This is because the dokan library needs WDK headers and libs.